# jquery calls controller twice for live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is relevant code for live/autocomplete search using jquery. The issue I'm facing is that every time I type a letter, it calls the controller twice.

My JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $('.tabs input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function() {
                    /* Get input value on change */
                    var inputVal = $(this).val();
                    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                    if (inputVal.length) {
                        $.get("live-search", {
                            term : inputVal
                        }).done(function(result) {
                            // Display the returned data in browser
                            console.log(result);
                            resultDropdown.html(result);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultDropdown.empty();
                    }
                });

                // Set search input value on click of result item
                $(document).on(
                        "click",
                        ".result p",
                        function() {
                            $(this).parents(".search-box").find(
                                    'input[type="text"]').val(
                                    $(this).text());
                            $(this).parent(".result").empty();
                        });
            });
</script>
```

My HTML code

```
<form class="simple-search-form">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">For Sale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">For Rent</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-hide">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Enter an address or city..." /> <input
                type="submit" value="GO" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-hide">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Enter an address or city..." /> <input
                type="submit" value="GO" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-hide">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Enter an address or city..." /> <input
                type="submit" value="GO" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any idea why it gets called twice every time I type a character?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is two event type are specified to on() function.
When type a character, "input" event will be fired at first, and "keyup" event will be fired next.
Try to specify only "input" event type.